# MSI GT80 turn on numpad?

Tags: touchpad

[image]

My laptop (MSI GT80) has a touchpad that becomes the numpad when you press the "num lock" button at the top-left of the touchpad. It works on Windows 8.1 & Win 10, but no on Ubuntu. The touchpad itself works, but I can't switch between touchpad and numpad. Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Running Ubuntu 15.10 x64 w/ Unity 7.3.2, kernel 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because the gt80's touchpad is software based, and not hardware based. You could install wine, and then install the software for the touchpad (probably a .MSI file, you'd have to find it), and see if it works then. Worth a try